# How to use socket.io-redis Nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, chat

Good afternoon,

I have a chat application written with NodeJS, Express and socket.io, in that application there are no rooms, when a user connects the socket (connection of that user) is linked to his id in an object that stays in memory:

```
Users = {
'1': {socket},
'2': {socket},
...
}
```

This works great! When a user is going to send a message it informs the recipient's id the server retrieves the equivalent socket and sends the message.

My problem is that due to the number of users I will have to upload a new server with the application, the problem is that users on different servers can not communicate because each server knows only the list of users that is connected to it. After much reading I came to the conclusion that the best way to solve this is by using the Redis Adapter, I looked for examples on the internet exhaustively however they all use Rooms to send the messages or send the same message to all the user and I would like to send one Message to a specific user regardless of which server instance it is if possible without the need to create rooms, simply recovering its connection based on its id and sending the message, would like to know if someone could tell me if this is possible and how to implement.

Below is an image of how my architecture should look:

[image]